# How do you factor this? $x^3 + x - 2$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, factoring

How do you factor $x^3 + x - 2$?

Hint: Write it as $(x^3-x^2+x^2-x+2x-2)$ to get $(x-1)(x^2+x+2)$

Note the factored form [here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x%5E3+%2B+x+-+2). Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By inspection, we see that $1$ is a root of $x^3 + x - 2$, so it is divisible by $x - 1$; alternatively, the rational roots theorem would suggest this too.

Now $x^2 + x + 2 = x^2 + x + \frac{1}{4} + \frac{7}{4} = (x + \frac{1}{2})^2 + \frac{7}{4}$ has no real roots, and is irreducible. If you're factoring over $\Bbb{C}$, then it's got roots at $\pm \sqrt{\frac 7 4}i - \frac{1}{2}$; denoting these as $\alpha_+$ and $\alpha_-$, the original polynomial then splits as

$$(x - 1)(x - \alpha_+)(x - \alpha_-)$$

Comment: Ok, duh, I should have recalled that I can test arbitrary roots with synth. division and find a factor, and use the depressed equation as the other factor.  However, I would not have thought to just notice that 1 is a root "by inspection" !!

Comment: The [rational roots theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_roots_theorem) in this case says the only possible rational roots are $\pm 1, \pm 2$.  Not many to try.

Comment: This forum rules.  Thanks for the nudge!  Closed.

Answer (score 3):

Note that the summation of the coefficients is $0$:
$$+1+1+(-2)=0$$
 so the polynomial has a factor like $(x-1)$.

Comment: I have never heard of this!
Can you explain the rule you're using?

Comment: @JackOfAll $a$ is a root of $P(x)$ iff $(x-a)$ is a factor of $P$.

Comment: Yea, but how do you know it's a factor just by summing the coefficients?

Comment: @JackOfAll: This works for every polynomial. The idea behind it is really in what Pedro noted. Try it. :)